# keep arrow visible fancybox

Tags: fancybox, visibility

In the photo gallery of Fancybox, the slide show has arrows disappearing and reappearing when moving the mouse. 
I want the arrows to remain visible. I used

```
    .fancybox-nav span {
    visibility: visible;}
```

but no result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `idleTime` option to change idle time or to disable completely -

```
$.fancybox.defaults.idleTime = false;
```